# $SU(2)$ symmetry and conservation law in condensed matter systems

Tags: condensed-matter, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

My question has a few parts,

I know from Noether that if there is a symmetry in a Hamiltonian, there is a conservation law.

1. What would be the conservation law associated with $SU(2)$ symmetry?
2. $SU(N)$ symmetry?
3. Can you give some physical intuition to these conservation laws?
4. My background is in condensed matter, if I perform an experiment where these symmetries are preserved and another where they are broken what differences should I expect to see?

I feel like I might have a fundamental misunderstanding of the subject.

Comment: Are you aware that Noether's theorem actually gives you the conserved current... Explicitly?